# Dynamic valdr-type

Tags: valdr, valdr-bean-validation

Would it be possible to have a dynamic `valdr-type`?  I am trying to build a dynamic form based off of nested objects and `valdr-type="{{constraint}}`, for example, but is not working.

Can valdr-type be dynamic or does it have to be set with `valdr-type="InsertStringHere"`?

Answer (score 0):

No, valdr does not yet support dynamic valdr types. I opened an issue for it: https://github.com/netceteragroup/valdr/issues/74